# Solutions in mscrm dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have few question regarding solution:

1. How to lock the solution in the mscrm dynamics 2011 ?
2. How would we manage , if multiple developer are working in the similar solution?
3. What is solution resolution conflict , How do we resolve ?

Comment: Re #2: You need to be *extra* careful, no tools to help teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no way to specifically lock the solution within Microsoft Dynamics CRM. We utilise TFS and Visual Studio to ensure that if a developer is working on Entity X, then they follow standard procedure to check in and check out the EntityX.OnLoad.js and EntityX.OnChange.js jscript files
2. Careful management of development tasks and who is working on what aspect of the solution. Where possible, we try to segregate entities to different developers at the beginning of the development phase. During the UAT/defect resolution phases, we make individual developers responsible for entire entities.
3. There is no automated way to resolve this, conflicts will have to be managed manually. It is very easy for a developer to overwrite somebody else's changes with a susequent publish of the solution. This is where it helps to use tools like TFS/VS.NET to manage the JScript. It doesn't, however, help with the form configurations.